# Why does my kitten village change name?

Tags: kittens-game

The second tab of the kittens game is where I force my kittens into labor. I noticed the name change sometimes but wasn't sure if my mind played tricks with me. Recently it happened again, and I know for sure now. Is this due to updates of the game, or related to some other in-game property?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I looked into the source code and it turns out to it is directly related to the amount of living kittens. The relevant part of the code is the following: (in [village.js](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/village.js?v=0.9.6.8))

```
getVillageTitle: function(){
    var kittens = this.game.village.getKittens();
    if (kittens > 300){
        return "Imperium";
    } else if (kittens > 200){
        return "Metropolis";
    } if (kittens > 150){
        return "City";
    } else if (kittens > 100){
        return "Town";
    } else if (kittens > 50){
        return "Small town";
    } else if (kittens > 30){
        return "Settlement";
    } else if (kittens > 15){
        return "Village";
    } else if (kittens > 0){
        return "Small Village";
    } else {
        return "Outpost";
    }
}
```

Right now I have 55 kittens, so I just upgraded from Settlement to Small Town. I am not going to try to kill some kittens to check if my village downgrades again, but it should.

Comment: While I can't refute source code, for some reason with 46 cats my settlement is called "Small Village". I should have moved to "Settlement" by now. I did remember my Small Village upgrading to Village but it no longer does

Comment: That's strange. Above is copied/paste from the source code so I didn't play any funny tricks with it. Should be Settlement indeed.

Comment: I frequently export/import my save to play on both work laptop and home PC. Perhaps that's the cause? Either way, can you find out when exactly does that function get called? Perhaps it's triggered by something

Comment: I will try, but I do the exact same thing. I export/import twice a day between University and home computer. It will be in the afternoon, I'm busy the next couple of hours.

Comment: I cannot really find exactly when it is updating, but when you buy a new loghouse/hut/mansion and you'll have a free kitten, there is a (1) or (2) next to the village-tab. Then it is updated. I think that was removed or updated every time I clicked something, so it updates pretty often.

Comment: You have to click to the "village" page and away again to get the title to update.